# Getting false even my values are equals when I am adding a new column to my object?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add another column on my script by doing a condition from the value of my storage object. I am confused why I am getting true response even the values are not equal. Maybe I missed something.

$storage =@()

$storage

```
Name : Mike
Username : Mike@@@@
groupname : Group1
ParentGroup : Group1 

Name : John
Username : John@@@@
groupname : Group1
ParentGroup : Group1 

Name : Rakesh
Username : Rakesh@@@@
groupname : Group1
ParentGroup : Group3 


$AddedMainGroupTable = $storage | MainGroupChoice -choice1 "Choice 1" -Choice2 "Choice2" -value1  $storage.groupname -value2 $storage.ParentGroup

function MainGroupChoice {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$InputObject,
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)] $value1,
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)] $value2,
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][String] $Choice1,
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][String] $Choice2
    )    

    process {
        if ($value1 -eq $value2 ) {
            return $InputObject |Add-Member -NotePropertyName MainGroup -NotePropertyValue $choice1 -PassThru  -Force
        }
        else {
            return $InputObject |Add-Member -NotePropertyName MainGroup -NotePropertyValue $Choice2  -PassThru  -Force
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Name : Mike
Username : Mike@@@@
groupname : Group1
ParentGroup : Group1 
MainGroup : Choice1

Name : John
Username : John@@@@
groupname : Group1
ParentGroup : Group1 
MainGroup : Choice1

Name : Rakesh
Username : Rakesh@@@@
groupname : Group1
ParentGroup : Group1 
MainGroup : Choice1
```

Comment: What is the content of `$table2`?

Comment: Hello zette. Its actually my $storage object. already updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $AddedMainGroupTable = $storage | MainGroupChoice -choice1 "Choice 1" -Choice2 "Choice2" -value1  $storage.groupname -value2 $storage.ParentGroup
> ```

When you use dot member access on an array, without indexing an array element, PowerShell collects the member from all elements of the array into a new array.
The effect is that you are actually passing arrays of all `groupname` and `ParentGroup` members as arguments for `-value1` and `-value2`. That's propably not what you want.

To pass only a single value for each `value*` parameter:

```
$AddedMainGroupTable = $storage | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | MainGroupChoice -choice1 "Choice 1" -Choice2 "Choice2" -value1 $_.groupname -value2 $_.ParentGroup 
}
```